# Is Java single-threaded or multi-threaded by default?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am not using any threading concept in my application - by default is it single or multi-threaded?

Comment: Often the IDE debugger should be able to show you how many threads are running.

Comment: What is *meant* by the question: that is, what is the *difference* between the two options provided?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Technically every Java application has quite a few threads (you can check with jvisualvm) but from a developer's point of view a command line application is single-threaded unless you explicitly create more threads or use an API call that specifies that it may run in a different thread. (e.g. [Runtime.addShutdownHook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)))

A special mention of those calls should go to the `Object.finalize()` method, which states:

> The Java programming language does not guarantee which thread will invoke the finalize method for any given object. It is guaranteed, however, that the thread that invokes finalize will not be holding any user-visible synchronization locks when finalize is invoked. If an uncaught exception is thrown by the finalize method, the exception is ignored and finalization of that object terminates.

This is probably the easiest way to accidentally create a multi-threaded application. It is also one of the reasons why the use of `finalize()` is strongly discouraged in general and should be limited to very specific cases, like freeing up native resources used by an object.

AWT and Swing applications however will almost always end up multi-threaded and therefore [extra care](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) should be taken with them.

Comment: Why should AWT/Swing applications be multi-threaded by nature? Many in fact aren't: everything except the minor entry-point code happens in the GUI thread.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Because you'll always have at least a GUI thread and an event dispatch thread.

Comment: What exactly is the GUI thread, in your opinion? People usually refer to the EDT as the GUI thread (and that's certainly what I did above), so I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sorry, you're right, I confused it with the fact that you can call `update()` from a different thread, but that only enqueues the paint request in the EDT. Nevertheless, thread safety (or rather the lack of it) is an important aspect of AWT and Swing, I'll rephrase my answer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik @biziclop is basically right but named the wrong threads. Swing applications have a minimum of two threads that run user code: the *main* thread and the GUI thread (same as EDT). Current best practice is for the main thread to nothing more than call `invokeLater` to do all the GUI work on the EDT, avoiding all thread-safety and memory visibility problems, then letting the main thread die. In practice people tend to do other stuff on the main thread.

Comment: And of course long-running operations should be moved off the EDT onto other threads or things like `SwingWorker` so this also brings in multi-threading. This is quite common though I wouldn't say it's inherent to Swing applications.

Answer (score 5):

Every Java application has a minimum of two threads (and there could be more). There is always the main or application thread and the garbage collector thread.

Comment: And the finalizer, so make that three.

Comment: @biziclop I think finalize is invoked in the [gc thread](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/finalize-method-in-java-tutorial.html) (at least in some versions of Java). And 3 > 2.

Comment: I don't think it's really fair to count the internal threads.. but it does add another perspective.

Comment: @user2864740 At least the *finalizer thread* is not all that internal: user-written code is being executed on it. So, whenever you implement a finalizer method, your codebase gets a new piece of code to be executed on the finalizer thread.